# Dragging From UITextView Produces Error with UITargetedPreview

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, uikit, uitextview

I have a subclass of UITextView that may include NSTextAttachments. I am attempting to implement UITextDragDelegate to allow dragging attachments from my app to another app. However, when a text attachment is starting to be dragged, the console shows the following message:

*"[Assert] CLIENT APP ERROR - Neither the view or container of the UITargetedPreview is currently in a window. This is in violation of UIDragInteraction API contract and can cause a severe visual glich. THIS IS A CLIENT APP BUG and will soon be a hard assert. PLEASE FIX ME"*

A search didn't produce many leads. One (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132829) said to use UIDragInteraction instead of UITextDragDelegate, but surely there must be a way to use this delegate properly. Here is relevant code. At first, I did not implement the dragPreviewForLiftingItem delegate method, but I later did in case that would help get rid of the error message. Please let me know your thoughts!

```
extension MyTextView: UITextDragDelegate {
    func textDraggableView(_ textDraggableView: UIView & UITextDraggable, itemsForDrag dragRequest: UITextDragRequest) -> [UIDragItem] {

        // We get the location in the text view in order to render the image preview and to get a reference to the attachment currently being dragged.
        let textRange = dragRequest.dragRange
        let dragPosition = self.offset(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: textRange.start)

        if let draggedAttachment = self.textStorage.attribute(.attachment, at: dragPosition, effectiveRange: nil) as? MyTextAttachmentClass {
            // Create the preview image and add it to a UIView.
            let renderer = UITextDragPreviewRenderer(layoutManager: self.layoutManager, range: NSMakeRange(dragPosition, 1))
            let image = renderer.image
            let thumbnailView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            thumbnailView.addSubview(imageView)

            draggedAttachment.fileType = "public.content" // Type handled in MyTextAttachmentClass
            let provider = NSItemProvider(object: draggedAttachment)
            let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: provider)
            // This is where we assign the preview to the drag item.
            dragItem.previewProvder = {
                return UIDragPreview(view: thumbnailView)
            }
            dragItem.localObject = draggedAttachment
            dragRequest.dragSession.localContext = renderer
            return [dragItem]
        }
    }

    func textDraggableView(_ textDraggableView: UIView & UITextDraggable, dragPreviewForLiftingItem item: UIDragItem, session: UIDragSession) -> UITargetedDragPreview? {

        guard let object = item.localObject as? MyTextAttachmentClass else { return nil }
        var attachmentImage = UIImage()
        if let renderer = session.localContext as? UITextDragPreviewRenderer {
            attachmentImage = renderer.image
        }
        let previewImage = UIImageView(image: attachmentImage)
        previewImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        previewImage.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: attachmentImage.size.width, height: attachmentImage.size.height)
        let center = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 20) // Using arbitrary center point for now
        let target = UIDragPreviewTarget(container: self, center: center)

        return UITargetedDragPreview(view: previewImage, parameters: UIDragPreviewParameter(), target: target)
    }
}
```

The preview is correctly presented and persists without visual glitches, but the error message tells me that something is wrong. Can someone help me understand where the issue is?  **Thank you all!**

Comment: As a follow-up, I created a simple app with a UITextView inside a UIViewController. I found that using the system default drag and drop with an NSTextAttachment image also produced the error message in the console.  Is it a bug maybe? Something to do specifically with a UITextView?

Comment: UPDATE: I have since updated Xcode to 14.1 and this warning is no longer presented.